# extjs 4 html editor submit issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have a html editor in my extjs form
The code that i useed for html editor is

```
{
                                  xtype: 'htmleditor',
                                  enableColors: false,
                                  enableAlignments: false,
                                  fieldLabel: 'Test',
                                  name      : 'test'
                            },
```

But when I try to submit it dont submits and gives the error below,

```
 TypeError: this.iframeEl is undefined
    [Break On This Error]   

    try {
```

Under extjs-debug.js.
Whats is the solution to overcome it.

---

Below is my submit code .

```
form.submit({
                url: 'some url',
                success: function(fp, o) {

                    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Success');
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                failure: function(fp, o) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Failed');
                }  
            });
```

Comment: Do you know which function it called? Callstack? What is your submit code?

Comment: Remove the extra `,` after name. But this is too few code to help.

Answer (score 0):

This TypeError usually gets thrown when the object is `undefined`. In your case the object `this` that doesn't have a `iframeEl` property.

Errors that are thrown in the library are 99% of the time your own fault ;)